# Least Squares Method Matrix when discriminant = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, discriminant

So I have a math question regarding the least squares method.
Given

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\0&0\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to derive the least-squares solution so I used $A^TAx=A^Tb$ with $A^T$ meaning $A$ transposed.

When calculating, I came to find that $$A^TA= \begin{bmatrix}2 &-4\\-4&8\end{bmatrix}$$

Now comes the problem. I have to get the inverse from this matrix, but the discriminant $= 0$. How do I solve this question when I can't inverse this matrix?

The final answer should be $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You should solve $A^\top A x = A^\top b$ for $x$. Assuming you've done the calculations correctly, you should find that this system of equations is consistent, and has the given solution.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thankyou, that helped!